# Why does WolframAlpha omit the $n=4$ and $n=8$ term in this Fourier series?

Tags: fourier-series, wolfram-alpha

I tried to determine the Fourier series of the function:

$$  f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x+\pi,  & -\pi \le x < -\frac{\pi}{2} \\
\frac{\pi}{2}, & -\frac{\pi}{2} \le x <\frac{\pi}{2} \\ \pi-x, & \frac{\pi}{2} \le x <\pi
\end{cases}$$

on Wolfram ([LINK](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ExptoTrig%5BFourierSeries%5BPiecewise%5B%7B%7Bx%2BPi,-pi%3C%3Dx%3C-Pi%2F2%7D,%7BPi%2F2,-Pi%2F2%3C%3Dx%3CPi%2F2%7D,%7BPi-x,Pi%2F2%3C%3Dx%3CPi%7D%7D%5D,x,9%5D%5D)) Alpha and for some reason there are no $\cos{4x}$, $\cos{8x},..$ terms. When calculating the coefficients of this series by hand I get: $$a_n =\frac{2 (-1)^{n-1}}{\pi n^2} \\b_n=0 $$

Which sort of reproduces what Wolfram Alpha says but I am not sure why terms are missing and why some of the coefficients don't match. Any ideas?

Comment: If coefficients are omitted, they should be $0$

Comment: I would also guess omitted terms are $0$. But I am no expert on wolfram software.

Comment: Computed by hand, the coefficients multiplying $\cos 4kx$ are zeros for $k=0,1,2,...$ One can also explain it with the use of the properties of those cosines: period, symmetry ... and the fact that the given function is even.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terms are there but have coefficients $0$, so they're omittted.

Your Wolfram results also lists no $\sin(nx)$ terms, also corresponding to your $b_n=0$.

The $a_n$ that don't match must be your own calculation errors.

Comment: Is there a way to calculate the formula for $a_n$ with wolfram alpha? (maybe this question is better suited for a different stackexchange site but maybe you know if it is possible)

Comment: @qmd you should know the formula for $a_n$ in terms of an integral, integration is easy in Wolfram alpha.

Comment: Good point! I don't know why I didn't think of that. I made a mistake integrating. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @qmd You're welcome!

Answer (score 3):

For
$$
\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x) \cos(nx)\;dx
$$
Maple gets
$$
2,-1,\frac{2}{9},0,{\frac{2}{25}},-\frac{1}{9},{\frac{2}{49}},0,{\frac{2}{81}},-\frac{1}{25},
{\frac{2}{121}},0
$$
for $n=1,2,\dots,12$.  (For $b_n$ you have to divide by the appropriate denominator.)

Comment: Yeah I made a mistake calculating the coeffcients. I just never know whether to trust my own calculations or the software. Thanks for your help!